# Is it the right approach to select the model when it gives highest accuracy on validation dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, cnn, finetuning, epochs

I am training the Densenet121 Model on an image dataset. I divided the dataset into 80% for training and 20% for testing.
Then I further divided the training data into 85% for training and 15% for validation. Now, after every epoch, I find the accuracy of the model. I save the model after the epoch in which it gives the highest accuracy on validation dataset. Then I evaluate this model on the completely unseen test dataset. Is this the right approach?

For example, I train the model for 10 epochs. After each epoch, the model gives following validation accuracies:

**Epoch 1:**  0.92 
**Epoch 2:**  0.925 
**Epoch 3:**  0.940 
**Epoch 4:**  0.943 
**Epoch 5:**  0.96 
**Epoch 6:**  0.95
**Epoch 7:**  0.955
**Epoch 8:**  0.958
**Epoch 8:**  0.95
**Epoch 9:**  0.95
**Epoch 10:**  0.94

Since the accuracy is highest after 5th epoch, I select the model after the 5th epoch, and then test it on the unseen test dataset.
I am suspecting that because I am selectively choosing the model with highest validation accuracy, I might be introducing bias in my model.